# Remove column without headers and data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV file and when I bring it to python as a dataframe, it create a new Unnamed: 1 column in dataframe. So how could I remove it or filter it.
[image: Here, whats my csv looks like]

So I need only Title and Date column in my dataframe not the column B of csv. Dataframe look like,

```
                                               Title  Unnamed: 1        Date
0  Đồng Nai Province makes it easier for people w...         NaN  18/07/2018
1  Ex-NBA forward Washington gets six-year prison...         NaN  10/07/2018
2                                Helicobacter pylori         NaN  10/07/2018
3     Paedophile gets prison term for sexual assault         NaN  03/07/2018
4                  Immunodeficiency burdens families         NaN  28/06/2018
```

Answer (score 2):

Drop that  column from your dataframe:

`df.drop(["Unnamed: 1"], inplace=True)`